# How to search files in directory using OR/NOT conditions?

Tags: windows, command-line, search, shell-script

I am able to search files that contain the term `plus` in a directory using the following command:

```
dir "*plus*" /s
```

However, I need to modify the command to search for files whose names contain the terms `plus OR vest`. In Windows Explorer, I am able to do this by entering search terms joined by `OR` like this - `plus OR vest`. How to accomplish this using windows command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dir` receives a list of patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) so you can just use multiple wildcard patterns

```
dir /s *plus* *vest*
```

You may want to use `dir /b /s *plus* *vest*` instead for saner output

---

Or you can also filter the result with `findstr`

```
dir /b /s | findstr /i "plus vest"
```

`findstr` will find words separated by spaces by default and will return lines that match `plus` or `vest`. `/i` is used to match case-insensitively, you can remove it if you don't want. But this method will be **much slower** because all the file paths must be printed out to the pipe

Note that this will also find all files in folders named `*plus*` or `*vest*`. You can remove `/b` but the output of `dir /b /s | findstr /i "plus vest"` will very confusing because you don't know which folder a file is in

---

To find (`plus` OR `vest`) but NOT `hoodie` use

```
dir /b /s *plus* *vest* | findstr /i /v hoodie
```

But that will also exclude files in folders named `*hoodie*`. Again removing `/b` helps but the output would be likely unhelpful. You should use PowerShell instead for such complex things. In fact I avoid writing anything new in cmd, PowerShell is significantly better, you don't have to learn the legacy quirks of cmd. In PowerShell that would be done as

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include "*plus*", "*vest*" | Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike "*hoodie*" }
```

or the shorter aliased version:

```
ls -R -I "*plus*", "*vest*" | where { $_.Name -notlike "*hoodie*" }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for `OR` condition. How to search for filenames that contain plus `OR` vest but `NOT` hoodie?

Comment: @dc09 that's out of scope of the OP. But please see the update

Answer (score 0):

With Powershell, you can use the following command:

```ps
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path\To\Your\Files\*" -Include "*plus*", "*vest*"
```

If you are already in the path:

```ps
Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -Include "*plus*", "*vest*"
```

Comment: there's a missing quote in your first command. And if you're already in path then you won't need `-Path`, but you'll need `-Recurse` to recurse into subfolders like `dir /s`. Additionally `-File` may be used to filter out just files

Comment: @phuclv Thanks for noticing about the missing quote.